# Does a sequence converge in $\mathbb{Q}$ if it's limit is irrational?

Tags: real-analysis

I'm uncertain whether I may state the following. Take the following sequence in $\mathbb{Q}$ defined by $a_n=\sqrt{2+\frac{1}{n}}$

Clearly, as $n\rightarrow\infty$, $a_n$ approaces $\sqrt{2}$. However, is it allowed to say that $a_n$ converges to $\sqrt{2}$? Or must I say that the limit is not defined, does not exist or something else?

Comment: No, it doesn't converge in $\mathbb{Q}$.  If it did, the limit would need to be in $\mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sequence you gave **is not** a sequence in $\mathbb{Q}$ since its elements are not in $\mathbb{Q}$. ($a_1 = \sqrt{3} \not\in \mathbb{Q}$)

To address your more central question, a sequence in $\mathbb{Q}$ that converges to an irrational point in $\mathbb{R}$ does not converge to any limit in $\mathbb{Q}$. For example, the sequence given by the recurrence

$$
a_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2} (a_n + \frac{2}{a_n}),\: a_0 = 1
$$

Converges to $\sqrt{2}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ and does not converge in $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: The fact that there exist Cauchy sequences in the rationals that do not converge is the central reason we need the reals to do analysis (or do analysis well, anyways)